# i couldn't open existing flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio-3.0

i have been imported flutter project and it worked well ,but i faced this problem when i tried to open it again.the project folders is not accessible as in the images

[[image: image 1]]
[[image: , image 2]]
 ,thus when tried to run the project from terminal i get the error that referred to in the image one.

### note:

the flutter path is set as in [[image: this image]]

Answer (score 0):

In your android Studio, right side you have **"gradle"** and **"Flutter outlie"** views. Out of which click on **gradle**. then right click on your root project and select **"sync project with gradle files"**

Then **enable dart support** in your project. To enable dart Go to **File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > Dart > Enable Dart Support**

This will solve your issue.